# Mongodb connection confuses and wanna updates, doesn't helps

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have node.js application with mongoose orm, mongo v3.2 and now I got this problem:

```
Error {
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal",
        "code": 352,
        "codeName": "UnsupportedOpQueryCommand",
        "$clusterTime": {
                "clusterTime": "7221220976820748299",
                "signature": {
                        "hash": "obbqzoIkdJCzJKAytBbGS23OTU0=",
                        "keyId": "7161825496127242251"
                }
        },
        "operationTime": "7221220933871075336",
        "name": "MongoError"
}
```

Maybe someone has this problem, please help me to solve it!

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Showing the code that generates an error is important to help diagnose any issue. _"The client driver may require an upgrade."_ <-- Did you try that?

Comment: How do I upgrade the client driver?